# Should I Delete a Question because of Typo?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, bad-questions

I recently asked this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782524/get-variable-from-header-file

Basically, I made a rookie mistake and forgot to include a modifier (or whatever it's called.)

The answer was obvious, and I just did not see it.

Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can't. Try to do it.

Comment: It says this and makes me scared:
Delete this answered question?

We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

Comment: AHA!! Click "delete question". You can't delete it :D

Comment: Not gunna risk it!  I did vote to close though :-)

Comment: Do I look like a leg puller?

Comment: Question asked by Evorlor.
Put on hold as off-topic by Evorlor.

Comment: wat? Don't be afraid, click delete and really try to delete it. It won't be deleted. The message will tell you why :D

Comment: If you leave it around long enough you can help the answerers get upvotes (and make it harder still to delete your question) while your question nets downvotes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you think your question and the answer of "it was a typo" will be helpful for future visitors?

If you don't think it will be, then delete it. If your not able to delete it since already has an upvoted answer or something, then just vote to close as a typo.