# Is it better to delete a question that ended up being user-error?

Tags: discussion

I asked for help with a problem in my code on stack overflow that ended up being a mistake on my part (I was referencing the wrong security role). Since the question itself cannot have a definitive answer and is more than likely not going to help anyone, would it be better to delete the question entirely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I Delete a Question because of Typo?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287096/should-i-delete-a-question-because-of-typo), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269605/my-question-turned-out-to-be-a-rather-esoteric-typo-what-should-i-do-what-sho, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320720/should-i-close-or-delete-my-question-caused-by-a-typo

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  If there's nothing of value there, there's no reason to keep it.